# How to convert a UTC date string in "2020-08-07T16:07:13.337248Z` to `MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm`` in est in Java

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, datetime-format

I have a string which is the date time represented in UTC "2020-08-07T16:07:13.337248Z" , I would like to convert this into EST in format "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm" in Java . Can anyone help me ?

Comment: Do you really want EST or do you want to adjust for Eastern Daylight Time?  EST in August does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

- Converts to [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) using the [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#BASIC_ISO_DATE).ISO_DATE_TIME format.
- Then converts back to desired format.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

String timeStr = "2020-08-07T16:07:13.337248Z"; 
String format = "MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm a";

ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime
    .parse(timeStr,DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("GMT-5")));
```

If you want to allow for `Daylight Savings Time` then do the following:

```
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStr, 
  DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME.withZone(ZoneId.of("EST5EDT")));
        
                
System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
```

Prints

```
08-07-2020 11:07 AM
```

I added the `a` in the format for `am` or `pm`.  If you want to see `EST` in the output, then put in `'EST'` after the `a`.

Comment: Thank you so much , this works but how can i convert this to EST , i.e. the UTC time is minus 4 hours

Comment: The use if java.time, the modern Java date and time API, is correct and recommended. The hand conversion to Eastern Time by subtracting 4 or 5 hours is not. Instead use a `ZoneId` and a `ZonedDateTime` and let Java handle summer time (DST) and other complicated stuff for you.

Comment: @OleV.V.  I agree, But I could not find an appropriate `ZoneId` for `Eastern Standard Time`.  So using `GMT-5` is, imo, no different than subtracting 5 hours.  They both require knowledge of the time zone difference.  If I use anything like `US/Eastern` it corrects for EDT.  The OP wanted EST.  I emended my answer but I would still rather find a less error prone solution.  And EST does not make sense in August.  But I was trying to respond to the OPs requirements.

Comment: I believe that time zones that use Eastern Standard Time all year include America/Panama, America/Jamaica, America/Atikokan, America/Coral_Harbour, America/Cayman and America/Cancun. If possible, pick according to why you want such a time zone. If you want a time zone with daylight time, prefer America/Montreal or America/New_York, again depending on what makes sense in relation to your requirements.